# Difference in usage of gerund and infinitive

Tags: gerunds, infinitives, infinitive-vs-gerund

> she did no more than sleep the whole day

Vs

> she did no more than sleeping the whole day

What is the difference in meaning of these two sentences?

Comment: Your first version is idiomatic, the second one isn't. But I don't think this is anything to do with "correct syntax" as such - it's just that the gerund / continuous verb form sounds clumsy to me.

Comment: Only your first example is correct. The sequence that follows "than" is a comparative clause and such clauses are finite. But "sleeping" heads a non-finite clause and hence is ungrammatical.

Comment: @BillJ How is *sleep the whole day* finite? The verb doesn't agree with the implied subject. Isn't it a bare infinitive?